# Redux Thunk for simple async requests

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I am building a simple app to retrieve some recipes from an API URL.
I am reading the documentation of Thunk to implement it but I cannot understand how to set the async get request. 
What is strange is that if I console.log the action passed into the reducer it definitely retrieves the correct object (a list of recipes for shredded chicken).
When I pass the action onto the the reducer, instead, it throws the error:

"Unhandled Rejection (Error): Given action "FETCH_RECIPES", reducer "recipes" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined."

Is there any error in my action creator? is the API call properly done?

Store

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import SearchBar from './components/App';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';



import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SearchBar />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
```

Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { Form } from 'reactstrap';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import  {fetchRecipe } from '../actions';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)


    this.state = { term: ''};
    this.typeRecipe = this.typeRecipe.bind(this)
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);  
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    this.props.fetchRecipe(this.state.term)
  }


  typeRecipe(e) {
    this.setState({term: e.target.value});

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
         <Form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
            <input type='text'
            value={this.state.term}
            placeholder='ciao'
            onChange={this.typeRecipe}
             />
             <br/>
            <Button id='ciao' className='btn-success'>Submit</Button>
         </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchRecipe }, dispatch);
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Action creator

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_RECIPES = 'FETCH_RECIPES';


const API_KEY = 'xxx';//not the real one.

export function fetchRecipe() {
   const request = axios.get(`http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY}&q=shredded%20chicken`);

   return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({data}) =>{
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_RECIPES, payload: data})
    })
}


}
```

reducer

```
import { FETCH_RECIPES } from '../actions';

export default function (state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_RECIPES:
            const newState = action.payload.data;                    
            return newState;
        default:
            return state
 }
}
```

combineReducer (index)

```
import recipeReducer from '../reducers/recipes_reducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    recipes: recipeReducer 
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Try `newState = action.payload` instead of `newState = action.payload.data;` in the reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake is in the reducer return statement.

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_RECIPES:
            const newState = {...state, data : action.payload.data};                    
            return newState;
        default:
            return state
 }
}
```

Here we are adding `data` key to the reducer state, to access this you can use do this in you container :

```
export default connect((state)=>{
    var mapStateToProps = {};
    if(state.recipes.data) {
        mapStateToProps['recipes'] =  state.recipes.data
    }
    return mapStateToProps;    

 }, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

and recipes data will be available as `this.props.recipes`.

Comment: It's throwing this error: "mapStateToProps() in Connect(SearchBar) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined." I think the container is still not receveing the data

Comment: @Enrico I have updated the code based on your error, check if the issue still exists

Comment: mmm, still nothing. when I render them using {this.props.recipes} still throws that error. in the network tab everuthing is fine so i suppose it is something wrong in the reducer or component

Comment: if you pass `null` instead of `mapStateToProps`, are you still getting the same error ?

Comment: yes...the render method cannot access the properties. I am uploading a repo on github if you want to give a better look

Comment: Sure give the link

Comment: i dont know how does it work with dependencies for the github installation, anyway I used redux, bootstrap, reactstrap, axios

Comment: thank you for being so patient :P....Actually when you try to access a property, like this.props.recipes.count it says it is undefined. if you try the console log you can see that the first log returns undefined, then if you click submit again it retrieves the recipes. Probably is a problem of async await

Comment: `this.props.recipes.count ` where are you writing it? in render function ?

Comment: in the consol.log that you set up in the onSubmit() method in App.js

Comment: onSubmit() , that function gets executed, and  re-rendering occurs, you can access `this.props.recipes.count` in render function. for that you don't have to click the button again.

Comment: now perfect :). What does it mean that && sign accessing the properties?

Comment: this is like if conditions in jsx.  You have to learn about them to use them

Comment: I will defintely take a step back and learn them. thanks for the support till here. If you have some nice source to learn or tutorial feel free to share